# How to convert a MQseries reason code to string?

Tags: c++, c, ibm-mq

How do i convert/lookup a reason code of IBM Websphere MQseries to its explanation (for logging etc)?

Answer (score 3):

Please see [SupportPac MA0K](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg24000652&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en) which has C and Visual Basic code to perform this task.

Comment: Great!  I was wondering where I might find this -- saved me a lot of work, @T.Rob

Answer (score 2):

Try using IBM Websphere MQ api: `char *MQRC_STR (MQLONG ReasonCode)`

Here is Sample code :

```
    #include <cmqc.h>
    #include <cmqstrc.h>
    typedef MQHCONN QM_REF;

    QM_REF connect(const std::string & QueueManagerName)
    {
        QM_REF theManager_ = -1;

        MQLONG compCode, reasonCode;
        MQCONN(const_cast<char *>(QueueManagerName.c_str()), &theManager_, &compCode, &reasonCode);
        if (MQCC_FAILED == compCode)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to connect to queue manager. Reason code is:" << MQRC_STR(reasonCode) << std::endl;
        }

        return theManager_;
    }
```

Comment: Why the down vote?  This shows how to use a function added in more recent versions IBM MQ that was not around when this question was asked in 2010.

Comment: Using stdout for error-reports is a _major_ anti-pattern :( That's what stderr is for.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line there is "mqrc.exe" which is supplied with MQSeries which returns the symbolic constant name.

And for Java there is MQConstants.lookupReasonCode(reasonCode) which is included in com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar